# Can hover to display an element that is neither a child or a sibling?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to make a div appear when the user hovers over another div. The problem is that the appearing div is neither a child nor a sibling of div the user should hover over. I made a jsfiddle to show what I mean [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L98jf429/).

How do I make the `#showMe` appear when the user hovers over the `#button`?

```css
#parent{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#button{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
#child, #sibling, #showMe{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:red;
    display:none;
}
#button:hover #child{
    display:block;
}
#button:hover + #sibling{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">parent
    <div id="button">button<div id="child">child</div></div>
    <div id="sibling">sibling</div>
</div>
<div id="showMe">showMe</div>
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do this. As you pointed out you can only do this with a child or sibling element. Using Javascript would be the next best thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your only option is to do it via Javascript 
Javascript:

```js
function showShowMe() {
    document.getElementById("showMe").style.display = "block";
}

function hideShowMe() {
    document.getElementById("showMe").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#parent{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#button{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
#child, #sibling, #showMe{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:red;
    display:none;
}
#button:hover #child{
    display:block;
}
#button:hover + #sibling{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">parent
    **<div id="button" onmouseover="showShowMe()" onmouseout="hideShowMe()">button<div id="child">child</div></div>**
    <div id="sibling">sibling</div>
</div>
<div id="showMe">showMe</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually it is not possible to achieve that that by pure CSS and you'd use JavaScript.

But in this particular case we can somehow fake the effect by using [adjacent sibling combinator `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) over the `#parent` instead, and giving a [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) of `none` to the parent and then re-setting the value of `pointer-events` to `initial` on the `#button` itself.

It's worth mentioning that [`pointer-events`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) on HTML/XML elements [is not supported in IE<=10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

**[Updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/hashem/L98jf429/3/)**

```css
#parent{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#parent:hover + #showMe {
    display: block;
}

#button{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    pointer-events: initial;
}
#child, #sibling, #showMe{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:red;
    display:none;
}
#button:hover #child{
    display:block;
}
#button:hover + #sibling{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">parent
    <div id="button">button<div id="child">child</div></div>
    <div id="sibling">sibling</div>
</div>
<div id="showMe">showMe</div>
```